# Fondness and Love, what is the difference?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I have a question, I got this message from a man.
He said some time ago, "take great care, this comes with fondest good wishes" then he changed to "take care, this comes with my love"

What is the difference between these two? I see fondest good wishes is use as a  sign off, but not the latter.

Comment: Ask him, not us. Our opinions will not settle the matter.

Comment: Thank you, Katherine. Maybe I'll ask him, you're right when it comes to people opinion about the meaning. I just merely ask the difference in the language perspective about fondness and love and I give an example of that. I hope that's ok

Comment: This is a question to be answered by philosophers and poets.

Comment: I guess the OP is asking for the difference _in common usage_ and that should be within the scope of ELU, unless I am missing something.

Comment: If you both know each other, and he's not married, around your age, single (i.e. no girlfriend), and ended a message (what was in the message?) with "take care this comes with my love" I'd say he's dropping hints.

Answer (score 1):

"**Best regards**", "**Best wishes**", "**Warm wishes**", "**Fondest good 
wishes**"

These phrases can all be grouped into the same category, [complimentary closes](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/01/with_best_wishe.html). These are all ways in which one can end an email or letter with proper etiquette. It's just a way of expressing consideration for the receiver of the message. I would say though that the second memo, "**this comes with my love**" most likely conveys some kind of affection for you. I have heard before that the phrase, "**with all the love from my heart**", is a common [love letter closing](http://www.healinglovenotes.com/perfect-love-letter.html).

So if I had to guess, the first message is more friendly while the second one is more loving. But of course, the best way to know is to ask him.